# David Williams "probability with Martingales" - three series theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a simple question about the Three series theorem:
[image: three series]

Suppose $\forall \omega, X_n(\omega)={1 \over n},n \ge 1$. then clearly $\sum_1^{\infty} X_n$ diverges but if $K=100$ then $P(|X_n|>K)=0$ and (i) is met.

Now this must mean that the $(X_n)$ are not independent.

My simple question: how does the definition of independence work in this case ?

After all, for any event A, $P(X_n= {1 \over n} | A) = P(X_n= {1 \over n})=1$ and $P(X_n \neq {1 \over n} | A) = P(X_n \neq {1 \over n})=0$

Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence of constant random variables $(X_i)_{i\geqslant 1}$  is always independent. This because 
$\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n\left\{X_i\in B_i\right\}\right)$ is equal to $1$ if $X_i$ belongs to $B_i$ for all $i$, and $0$ otherwise, which is the same as $\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb P\left(\left\{X_i\in B_i\right\}\right)$.

What fail here is that if we choose $K\gt 1$, then $X_n^K=X_n$ and condition (ii) does not hold.

Comment: many thanks Sir !